# Интерфейс с атрибутом

Tags: c#

Можно ли использовать атрибуты с интерфейсами, так что бы реализующий класс имел метод с таким же атрибутом ?

Comment: почему бы просто не попробовать?

Comment: @Grundy Галилей тоже мог бы бросать легкий и тяжелый предмет с Пизанской башни. Но он предпочитал рассматривать это *умозрительно*.

Comment: @Grundy попробовал с `TestClassAttribute` получил ошибку `Attribute not valid on declaration type`. При этом кастомный атрибут `SomeAttribute` можно применить к интерфейсу но реализующий класс может спокойно атрибута не иметь, это не приведет к ошибке а хочется именно обязать имплементирующий класс иметь указанный `SomeAttribute`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, атрибуты интерфейсов не наследуются реализующими их классами.

Если вы хотите наследуемые атрибуты, придется использовать абстрактный класс вместо интерфейса. При этом необходимо явно указать что атрибут наследуется (свойство `Inherited` в `AttributeUsage` атрибута) и при его получении необходимо явно указать, что нас интересуют наследуемые атрибуты (параметр `inherit` в семействе методов `GetCustomAttribute[s]`):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            typeof(C1)
                .GetMethod(nameof(C1.Method))
                .GetCustomAttribute<InheritanceAttribute>( // <== using System.Reflection;
                    inherit: false) is InheritanceAttribute
        ); // False

        Console.WriteLine(
            typeof(C1)
                .GetMethod(nameof(C1.Method))
                .GetCustomAttribute<InheritanceAttribute>(
                    inherit: true) is InheritanceAttribute
        ); // True

        Console.WriteLine(
            typeof(C2)
                .GetMethod(nameof(C2.Method))
                .GetCustomAttribute<NonInheritanceAttribute>(
                    inherit: false) is NonInheritanceAttribute
        ); // False

        Console.WriteLine(
            typeof(C2)
                .GetMethod(nameof(C2.Method))
                .GetCustomAttribute<NonInheritanceAttribute>(
                    inherit: true) is NonInheritanceAttribute
        ); // False

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = true)]
class InheritanceAttribute : Attribute { }

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = false)]
class NonInheritanceAttribute : Attribute { }

abstract class AC1
{
    [Inheritance]
    public abstract void Method();
}

abstract class AC2
{
    [NonInheritance]
    public abstract void Method();
}

class C1 : AC1
{
    public override void Method() { }
}

class C2 : AC2
{
    public override void Method() { }
}
```

А вот здесь пояснение от разработчиков языка, по поводу наследования атрибутов от интерфейса: [Forums: Code First DataAnnotations in Interfaces](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1748587a-f13c-4dd7-9fec-c8d57014632c/code-first-dataannotations-in-interfaces?forum=adonetefx)

Comment: Понятно, спасибо за ссылку

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно: https://ideone.com/gObRwA

```
using System;

class SomeAttribute : Attribute {}

[Some()]
interface I
{
  void Method();
}

public class Test : I
{
  [Some()]
  public void Method() {}

  public static void Main(){}
}
```

Comment: Хоть `Test` и реализует `I`но  можно спокойно удалить `[Some()]` и ошибки компиляции не последует.

Comment: @Сергей, и что? Атрибуты вообще никогда не дают ошибку компиляции.

Comment: @Qwertiy, вообще-то дают, если ставить атрибут не туда, куда разрешает `AttributeUsage`: [Compiler Error CS0592](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0592)

Comment: @Qwertiy дают ошибку, так же в случае если настроен анализатор Roslyn на опр. поведение. Например ObsoleteAttribute с флагом IsError = true.

Comment: @Qwertiy атрибут [TestClass] вызовет ошибку компиляции на интерфейсе